# Restangular does support withCredentials options and the other options for a cors request?

Tags: angularjs, cors, restangular

I'm googling but I don't find any clue on

if restangular support withcredentials option and the other options for a cors request or not.

I mean can I use it in a cors calls without any issues ?

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes it does.

You can set them by using `setDefaultHttpFields`: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaulthttpfields

It has the same format as $http values.

Comment: thanks so like RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({withCredentials: true}); ?

Comment: Exactly, that's the way to do it