# How to persist authenticated state in a sailsJS backend app when requests are from another domain?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, sails.js

I have an architecture where I'm using sailsJS (custom node.js implementation) as my api server and an angular front end server.  Each app is being served from different domains.

How can I maintain an authenticated session in the sailsJS api app between requests?

Sails has an integrated req.session object for maintaining sessions but it doesn't seem to be working out of the box when the client is being served from another domain.

Comment: How is the front-end app communicating with Sails?  Via [Angular $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)?

Comment: I'm using restangular for http calls but i also need socket.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check two things when doing cross-origin requests from your front-end app to your Sails app:

1. Make sure your Sails app [has CORS enabled](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Security/CORS.html); this will ensure that the browser doesn't block the requests for security reasons
2. Make sure the `withCredentials` flag is set in your AJAX request; this will ensure that your cookie is sent to Sails and your session is maintained.

With Restangular, you can set `withCredentials` to be used on all requests by default using `setDefaultHttpFields`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325694/345484) for details.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to work.  I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.  I was not familiar of the withCredentials requirement.