# Angularjs ng-src not working with basic authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page in my application which has a ng-src directive that must fetch a image from a server that requires basic authentication. The basic authentication is already setup on my app, and all requests are working this way. However, the image are not loading with ng-src directive. How could I fix this problem?

Thanks for any help.

```
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
        $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
```

Comment: please share your code, what you have done.

Comment: Ho do you set the authentication? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and, at least for me, it was caused by Restangular not sending a cookie header.  I had to add "withCredentials: true" when configuring.  See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324125/restangular-does-support-withcredentials-options-and-the-other-options-for-a-cor)